# iterate over this generic SET with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, collections

I cannot find a way to iterator over the SET below  using wildcards. I have also tried to convert it like it is mentioned in Effective Java but still get compilation error.

```
public void testWildCardIteration() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, ?> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet = // entries....

    iterHelper(entrySet, result);

}

private <E> void iterHelper(Set<Map.Entry<String, E>> entrySet , LinkedHashMap<String, E> result) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, E> entry : entrySet) {
        String tmpkey = entry.getKey();

        if (tmpkey.startsWith("KEY")) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `E` method scoped is not required.
As it doesn't specify any bound, it uses `Object` by default.

Instead, specify `?` as type of `Entry.value` of `entrySet` and specify `Object` as type of `Entry.value` of `result`.
Note that you cannot specify `?` as type such as `Set<?>` as you want to add not `null`s in a collection. But with `Object` such as `Set<Object>` you can do it.

```
private  void iterHelper(Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet , LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entrySet) {
        String tmpkey = entry.getKey();

        if (tmpkey.startsWith("KEY")) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

You can now invoke it :

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet = ...;
iterHelper(entrySet, result);
```

Comment: Thanx !!!!! I was a bit stacked since i wanted to finish an implementation to a generic interface towards a distributed cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards in the read only collection. But you will have to use a `super` lower bounded wildcard applied to the collection to which you are writing.

In essence this should compile:

```
public void testWildCardIteration() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, ? super Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // write collection 
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet = new HashSet<>(); // read collection

    iterHelper(entrySet, result);

}

private void iterHelper(Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet, LinkedHashMap<String, ? super Object> result) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entrySet) {
        String tmpkey = entry.getKey();

        if (tmpkey.startsWith("KEY")) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a simple test which shows the code working:

```
public static void testWildCardIteration() {

    LinkedHashMap<String, ? super Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet = new HashSet<>();

    entrySet.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Object>("KEY", "BLAH"));
    iterHelper(entrySet, result);

    System.out.println(result);
}

private static void iterHelper(Set<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entrySet, LinkedHashMap<String, ? super Object> result) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : entrySet) {
        String tmpkey = entry.getKey();

        if (tmpkey.startsWith("KEY")) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    testWildCardIteration();
}
```

This prints out:

```
{KEY=BLAH}
```

Comment: The lower-bounded  wildcard is not required. Specifying Object is enough as you pass a collection of Object  to a collection of Object parameter.  You don't pass a subtype.  I did the same mistake and I updated then :)

Comment: @davidxxx I think you are right, you can skip the lower bounded wildcard and simply use Object on the `LinkedHashMap`. But you cannot use just the '?' wildcard on its own on the `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Sure. Java is sometimes a little (too) complex about generics.

Comment: Thanx !!!!! I was a bit stacked since i wanted to finish an implementation to a generic interface towards a distributed cache. It was easier than i thought ! But for me since i was stacked to the wildcard representation ...